# Add flex-grow to material ui Grid

Tags: material-ui

Is it possible to add "flex-grow" to a Grid item in material ui? Seams a bit weird that I have to choose Box in order to get access to Flexbox https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add `flex-grow` using the style attribute.

```
<Grid item style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
   <Typography variant="h1" color="textPrimary" >
      Title
   </Typography>
</Grid>
```

or you can create a separate class for multiple Grid items.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Amir's answer, but uses a styled component:

```
const StyledGridItem = styled(Grid)({
  flexGrow: 1
})
```

Then implemented...

```
<StyledGridItem item>
  // contents of grid item here
</StyledGridItem>
```